# htaccess to only redirect to subdir if domain is not X

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, wildcard

**The situation:** So I have a several domains pointing to the same website. The domain is the variable on which some scripts are run. There's only one domain which acts as the default (ex. default.tld).

**The problem:** I want the domain default.tld to be left alone but all other domains have to redirect to `http://wildcarddomain.tld` to `http://wildcardomain.tld/home`

**What I tried:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?default.tld [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/home [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately this gets me into a redirect loop. Maybe its something else causing this, but I want to be sure that it's not my htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is almost correct but `RewriteRule` is problem and will cause redirect loop as you're matching `.*` which will always match.

You need to use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?default\.tld$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home [R=301,L]
```